# Update нескольких строк через php в mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Всем Добра! Подскажите, как сделать Update нескольких строк таблицы через php и отправить в mysql(строки таблицы динамические их может быть от 1 до N.). Данные строк таблицы формы предаю через ajax в php, загвоздка как раз как сделать Update. Спасибо всем!

Comment: Загнать их во временную таблицу, а потом одним запросом разложить по местам. Ну или сгенерить большой UPDATE запрос? который парсит собранные в кучу значения и распихивает по записям. Вы бы поконкретнее - показали структуру таблицы, пример данных, пример полученного через аякс, и то, что должно получиться в таблице.

Comment: Разобрался, оказывается просто не правильно был написан SQL запрос на UPDATE.  Сделал через foreach. Правильно это или не правильно, красиво или нет я не знаю, может и есть более элегантный способ. Спасибо за ответ.